# Why is this string reverse program not working?

Tags: c

This is a program for string reverse without using the `strlen()` and `strrev()` functions. Please help me regarding this code: the `length` function shows `11` but the `reverse` function is not working.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

int length(char*);
char *reverse(char*);

main() {
    printf("%d", length("himanshupal"));
    printf("%s", reverse("himanshupal"));
    getch();
}

/* used to calculate the lenghth*/
int length(char *p) {
    int l;

    for (l = 0; *(p+l) != '\0'; l++);
    return (l);
}

char *reverse(char *p) {  // function for reversing the string
                          // l used for length
    int i, l;
    char t;

    for (l = 0; *(p+l) != '\0'; l++);
    for (i = 0; i < l / 2; i++) {
        t = *(p+i);
        *(p+i) = *(p+l-1-i);
        *(p+l-1-i) = t;
    }
    return (p);
}
```

Comment: When you say that the program is not working, what do you mean by that? Do you get build errors? Then post the exact errors you get. Do you get crashes? Then run in a debugger to locate where it happens. Do you get unexpected result? Then please show us the actual and expected output. Also please [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: The type of a string literal is `const char*`.  That your program compiles anyway is a tragedy that every C programmer has to learn the Hard Way.

Comment: i save my program with length.exe . after running length function shows 11. but after than green line running window popups and shows length.exe is not running properly

Comment: @HansPassant IIRC that's not strictly true in C, only C++. String literals are supposed to be read-only and immutable arrays, but still decay to `char *` rather than `const char *`. I remember having seen it in the C specification, but can't remember where at the moment.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: 6.4.5p6 at least does not mention it is `const char []` (it never is/has been a pointer!), p7 makes modification UB but also without adding `const`ness. The standard even mentions making string literals mutable as a typical compiler extension.

Answer (score 1):

String literals are immutable in C and C++. Any attempt to modify a string literal results in undefined behavior.:)

Use character arrays instead. for example

```
    int main( void )
    //^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    {
        char s[] = "himanshupal";
        printf( "%d\n", length( s ) );
        printf( "%s\n", reverse( s ) );
        getch();
    }
```

Take into account that it is better to declare the function length like

```
size_t length( const char * );
```

Comment: thanks brother its working but what is wrong in my code

Comment: @HimanshuPal You are using string literal in the call     printf("%s", reverse("himanshupal")); and the function reverse tries to change it.

Comment: in which way it change the call?

Comment: @HimanshuPal It changes the string literal passed to the function reverse as an argument.

Comment: @HimanshuPal A string literal like `"himanshupal"` is a ***read only*** string. You should not attempt to modify it. When you create an array like `s` in the example in this answer, that array is in memory that *can* be modified.

Comment: @joachim: he says it works in Turbo C, but that is a very old, non-compliant compiler. There, literals were perhaps not in read-only memory.